# no access to windows phone 7 marketplace

Tags: windows-phone-7, installation, marketplace

My country has no access to the WP7 MarketPlace but i want to know if i can still at least develop apps for my own WP7 Device or at least directly install it on other devices that i have access to..

Thanks

Comment: This has already been asked on Programmers' (not the same user though) -http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/20616/finding-a-publisher-for-windows-phone-marketplace-im-from-an-unsupported-count

Comment: Great..i guess i need to look for someone who can publish the apps on my behalf..Thanks Chris..

Answer (score 2):

You can still develop applications for the countries that do have a WP7 MarketPlace and you can add your applications to an unlocked device without needing access to the MarketPlace by using the Application Deployment tool, which is part of the [Windows Phone7 Development Tools](http://create.msdn.com). In order to unlock your phone, you will need to create an account on the [App Hub](http://create.msdn.com) and register as a developer.

Comment: Thanks Derek but thats the problem..I cant register on AppHub..My country (Nigeria) isn't there...Even if i want to develop apps for on my own device, i still need to unlock it, which requires registration on Apphub (which i cant do)..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a response I have seen on other forums that appears useful;
Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone - http://www.microsoft.com/express/Phone/

As for installing on other devices, I'm not sure how that would work. I believe the way Windows7 works is different to the typically CAB file installation on Windows6 (Mobile) downward

Answer (score 0):

My country (the Netherlands) also has no marketplace yet. 
If you buy a WP7 developer license you can still unlock your phone and use it to develop applications regardsless. You can even publish your app on the marketplace for alll countries that have it. But you couldn't download it from that marketplace yourself...
(A developer licese allows you to unlock up to three phones regardless of the liveID used on them, I have currently unlocked two of my collegues as well and I can use the webinterface to revoke this without needing their phone)

What you can also do is create a seperate live_id with a country that does have a marketplace and use that as the **root** liveID for your phone. In that case you could download your own app providing it is either free or you can somehow pay in that country (ie prepaid us creditcard). Unfortunately because it has to be the primary ID you will have to reset your phone and you will still need a Wp7 dev account.

I went through all these hoops myself

Comment: Is there a way to register on Apphub without country info?

Comment: No sadly there isn't. What you can do is register it for all countries and then in the text add the message that it only supports <your country>. From personal experience I can tell you that you will still get negative feedback from this though. My app is called 'Verkeer' or Traffic in Dutch. It explicitly says in the description that it only works in holland but it still has 3 negavtive ratings beceause it doesn't work in <X>. Understandable from a enduser perspective but rather frustrating I must admit

Answer (score 0):

i found a site called www.yallaapps.com that can take care of those of us without access to the marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the Windows Phone Developer Blog.
There have been some changes regarding this issue.
This [blog post](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/03/08/an-update-on-windows-phone-marketplace-new-tips-policies-and-regional-access-program.aspx) from ms team offer an alternative for publishing apps via **Global Publisher Program.**